# Transistors choice for buck boost converter using LM34936

Tags: buck-boost, powermosfet

I've been using TI's Webench online design tool for buck boost design purposes that uses [LM34936](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm34936.pdf?ts=1614687167497).

The simplified schematic in LM324936's datasheet looks:

[image]

Webench design tool generated 4 different MOS transistors (CSD series):

M1 [CSD16321Q5](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd16321q5.pdf);
M2 [CSD18511Q5A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18511q5a.pdf);
M3 [CSD17303Q5](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd17303q5.pdf);
M4 [CSD17573Q5B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd17573q5b.pdf);

[image]

My question is, could I use one just type of transistors instead of 4 different?
The output I'm trying to get is 12V, so what is the maximum Vds that could occur on MOS' drains?

Comment: export/post link to WebBench design

Comment: Section 9.2.2.13 of the data sheet explains why different transistors are used.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Here's the link https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=E5417292DAEB594A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Voltage rating and  current ratings depends on each FET due to your Vin Max/Min Vgs and Vout.

If you reduce the range on input voltages, it is possible to have more common parts but \$Q_g\$ and \$Q_{gd}\$  increase with Vds and lower RdsOn which depends on these VI in/out ranges as a slower rise time also increases losses.

Comment: The input voltage is around 12V (+/-2V), so basically I would have to consider double the voltage of that on the input FETs' Vds, like 24V Vds rating? Is my thinking right?

Comment: Yes and also Buck-boost converters underperform when input equals output with noise